# ¿Que ocurre si no asigno un valor a una variable y lo imprimo?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Se que puede sonar como una pregunta muy basica/tonta. Pero para poner un ejemplo en Pascal,

```
Program prueba ;
var
  a : integer ;
begin
  write(a) ;
end.
```

Por ejemplo si me preguntaran que imprime en pantalla el write(a) que seria lo que imprime?

Comment: Lo probaste? Qué pasó cuando lo probaste?

Comment: Dio 0. Pero en la teoria queria confirmar si a lo que nos referimos es contenido basura o residuo.

Comment: en lineas generales es lo que hay en esa posición de memoria al momento de acceder, a fines prácticos puede considerarse contenido basura o residual. entre el compilador y el sistema puede llegar a darte siempre 0 peero como no es parte del estándar del lenguaje ( asegurarse que sea 0 ) no es algo de que confiarse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La [documentación](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse24.html) dice en perfecto español

> By default, simple variables in Pascal are not initialized after their declaration. Any assumption that they contain 0 or any other default value is erroneous: They can contain rubbish.

Que dice más o menos que Pascal no las inicializa al declararlas y pueden contener cualquier cosa. Así pues, es sano declararlas e inicializarlas antes de usarlas por primera vez, teniendo en cuenta el *scope* correspondiente.

Indican también que hay dos excepciones a este comportamiento:

- *Managed types* son una excepción a esta regla: Siempre se inicializan con un valor por defecto: en general, esto significa fijar el reference count en cero o fijar el apuntador a Nil
- Las variables globales se inicializan con el equivalente a cero.

Y recordar que siempre se inicializan, ocupan lugar en memoria recién cuando el programa llega al scope correspondiente.

PD. No es una pregunta tonta. Es de hecho, muy importante y preguntarse este tipo de cosas es lo que previene bugs futuros. En general, inicializar y controlar el valor inicial es buena práctica (salvo en casos en los que ciertos tipos de dato aseguran un valor por defecto útil, por lo que te ahorra trabajo de preparar todo para trabajar. Pero para hacer ésto con certeza siempre hay que revisar la documentación).

Comment: Creo también es importante acostumbrarse a las expresiones "valor predeterminado" y "de manera predeterminada" al traducir "by default". De esta manera si no es el programador, será el sistema el que (previamente) determina el valor inicial de las cosas